# How to Remove sshpass from linux

Tags: linux, ssh

Ok this might sound ridiculous but How do you remove `sshpass` package ???

The way I installed it was this:

```
$ tar -zxvf sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
$ cd ./sshpass-1.05
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

So this installed `sshpass` on the machine. However, When I want to remove it, it doesn't get fully removed.

Also, Please note that I cannot use the following remove command since the servers don't support them. `sudo-apt remove`

I've also tried `rpm` but doesn't work....any help?

Answer (score 0):

`make uninstall` will sometimes work. I don't know whether it will work for `sshpass`.

---

In future, you can use [xstow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/) to provide `make uninstall` functionality for **any** package. But this won't help you to uninstall packages you've already installed.